# Compile Ruby Enterprise Edition on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, compilation

Hi
when trying to compile Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02

```
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:734: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:734: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:734: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I tried also specifying the option -c '--with-readline-path=/usr/local'  (where I installed the readline libs), but I have the same issue.

I tried to install readline with port and delete my manual compile, but the problem still there.

I never had troubles under Linux (the system I'm used to), having ldconfig, etc...

HELP! :)

Thanks

Comment: What version of OS X? Snow or snowless leopard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved in this way:

I compiled readline 5.2 following this guide
http://techdebug.com/blog/2009/01/03/compiling-readline-on-an-osx-105-intel-x86_64/

readline 6.1 does not work with ree.

Doing the installation with the following:

```
./installer -c '--with-readline-dir=PATH'
```

works fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using RVM ([Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/))?

Comment: The next thing I'd do is see what'd happen if I tried installing other rubies using RVM, to see if it's specific to REE or not.

Comment: Also, did you come across [this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/136498) in Ruby forum?

Comment: yes I saw that.
I will try again later or tomorrow when I have time, cleaning the readline lib, trying again, trying another ruby version with rvm, and see where I end up. Thanks anyway